# Get Element By ? tag name id or class name How do you get the innertext of below

Tags: excel, vba, scrape, innertext, htmldoc

The UPS Website changed.  Instead of the tag  it change to

```
Private Function TrackUPS(trackingNumber As String) As String
    Dim xml As Object
    Dim tempString As String
    Dim htmlDoc As Object  ' MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim htmlBody As Object  ' MSHTML.htmlBody
    Dim anchors As Object  ' MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim anchor As Object  ' MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim dds As Object  ' MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim ddr As Object
    Dim dt As Object
    Dim dd As Object  ' MSHTML.IHTMLElement

    'tempString = GetMSXMLWebResponse(UPSUrl & trackingNumber)

    Set xml = GetMSXML
    If xml Is Nothing Then  ' cannot start MSXML 6.0
        TrackUPS = MSXML_ERROR
        Exit Function
    End If

    tempString = GetResponse(xml, HTTP_GET, UPSUrl & trackingNumber, False)

    If Len(tempString) = 0 Then
        TrackUPS = ERROR_MSG
        Exit Function
    End If

    Set htmlDoc = CreateHTMLDoc
    If htmlDoc Is Nothing Then  ' cannot reference MSHTML object library
        TrackUPS = MSHTML_ERROR
        Exit Function
    End If

    Set htmlBody = htmlDoc.body
    htmlBody.innerHTML = tempString
    On Error Resume Next
    Set dds = htmlDoc.getElementsByclassname("").innerText
    'Set dds = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("dd")
    Set ddr = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("dt")
    Strg1 = htmlDoc.getElementById("tt_spStatus").innerText
    Strg2 = dds.Item(1).innerText
    Strg3 = dds.Item(11).innerText
    Strg4 = htmlDoc.getElementById("tt_pgfStatus").innerText
    Strg5 = htmlDoc.getElementById("tt_ovntStatus").innerText
    If Len(Strg1) = 0 Then
        Strg1 = Strg4
        If Len(Strg4) = 0 Then
            Strg1 = Strg5
        End If
    End If
    PODEnd10 = Strg1 & "|" & Strg2
    If PODEnd10 = "|1.   " Then GoTo Line1 Else GoTo Line2
    Line2:
    If PODEnd10 = "|>>>1." Then GoTo Line1 Else GoTo Line3
    Line3:
    TrackUPS = Strg1 & "|" & Strg2
    Exit Function
    Line1:
    TrackUPS = "NO|POD|INFO"
    Exit Function
End Function
```

So the website shows the Day and Time with this:

```
<p class="">
    Monday, &nbsp;01/11/2016
    at&nbsp;9:09 A.M.
</p>
```

I use this in the above code:
    Set dds = htmlDoc.getElementsByclassname("").innerText
However the `<p class="">` has no name.  How do I capture the innertext of that element?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I rely on this daily.

Here is the entire div class:

```
<div class="ups-group ups-group_condensed">
p class="ups-form_label"><strong>Delivered On:</strong></p>

<p class="">
    Monday, &nbsp;01/11/2016
    at&nbsp;9:09 A.M.
</p>
</div>
```

What would be the .innertext coding in vba to return the Monday and the date and time of the P class""?

Comment: `class=""` means the element has no class. You can't find it using `getElementsByClassName`. There is no such thing as a class whose name is an empty string. There is also no reliable way, other than searching the entire DOM, to find elements with no classes, although you could try `[class=""]` (not tested).

Comment: What would that look like?  I don't understand what the code would look like.  Can you please provide an example.

Comment: Can someone please provide a complete solution to return the innertext of the following? <p class="">
    Monday, &nbsp;01/11/2016
    at&nbsp;9:09 A.M.
</p>

Comment: Alas, web-reading is always vulnerable to changing webpages. Unless you go through an API(why not ask or try https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit/downloadresource?loc=en_US?), you will have to tweak occasionally. Here without classes or ids for the relevant tag, you just have to get a path which works: Try to get the <div> maybe by its classname, and then myDiv.getElementsByTagName("P")(2).innerText

Comment: @macromarc You saved my bacon sir.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
Set dds = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("p")
Strg2 = dds.Item(11).innerText
```